# Updating a record with to_sql

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use Pandas to compare a df from a text file against a df from a sql database. When an item is different in the text file df I wish to insert or if I already have it in the database update that field.

```
# Text File
# "Id","Stock_ID","Colour"
# "298","203","Green"

df1 = pd.read_table("data.txt", sep = ",")
df2 = pd.read_sql_table("mytable", con=engine)


df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1], sort=False).drop_duplicates(subset = . 
["Stock_ID"], keep=False)
df4 = df3.loc[pd.isnull(df3.id)] # This contains the new record to update

df4.to_sql('feed', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index_label='id', 
dtype={
    'id': sqlalchemy.INTEGER(), 
})
```

`df4.to_sql` throws an error of `ValueError: duplicate name in index/columns: cannot insert id, already exists`.

How can I update a row in the database by id?

Comment: Be careful with the `if_exists` option. Based on [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), it looks like it will _drop the table_, which is likely not what you want (though maybe it is, based on what your desired outcome is). Also, are you sure that you don't have duplicate IDs in your text file?

Comment: @JonahBishop True, I don't want to drop the table, just update a record. I'm sure there are no duplicate IDs in the text file.